# Error when using tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to use lstm with projection in tensorflow2.0 .
I am writing a custom model, however I am getting error

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4096 and 2288 for 'transducer/rnn_model/encoder_lstm1/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [4,4096], [2288,8192].

Below is the code:

```
class RNNModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, input_size, vocab_size, hidden_size=2048, num_layers=8, dropout=.2, blank=0, bidirectional=False):
    super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.blank = blank
    self.lstm_layers = []
    self.proj_layers = []
    self.lstm_proj_layers = []
    self.batch_norm_layers = []
    self.proj_dim = 640
    rnn_size = hidden_size
    output_dim = rnn_size
    self.cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(2048, num_proj=2048)
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        name1='encoder_lstm'+str(i)
        self.lstm_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.cell, return_sequences=True, name=name1))

  def reshape_pyramidal(self, outputs):
    shape = tf.shape(outputs)
    batch_size, max_time = shape[0], shape[1]
    num_units = outputs.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    pads = [[0, 0], [0, tf.math.floormod(max_time, 2)], [0, 0]]
    outputs = tf.pad(outputs, pads)
    concat_outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size, -1, num_units * 2))
    return concat_outputs

  def call(self, x, xlen):
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
      output = self.lstm_layers[i](inputs=x)
      x = output
    return x, state_h
```

Following is the error

```
    train_proj.py:92 train_step  *
    xs, _ = self.encoder(xs_1, xlen)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
/home/ubuntu/E2E-ASR/model_proj.py:84 call  *
    output = self.lstm_layers[i](inputs=x)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py:623 __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py:756 call
    zero_output_for_mask=self.zero_output_for_mask)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:4035 rnn
    input_time_zero, tuple(initial_states) + tuple(constants))
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py:732 step
    output, new_states = self.cell.call(inputs, states, **kwargs)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py:1028 call
    array_ops.concat([inputs, m_prev], 1), self._kernel)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py:180 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py:2765 matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:6136 mat_mul
    name=name)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py:793 _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py:548 create_op
    compute_device)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:3429 _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1773 __init__
    control_input_ops)
/home/ubuntu/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1613 _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4096 and 2288 for 'transducer/rnn_model/encoder_lstm1/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [4,4096], [2288,8192].
```

Comment: Please include an example of how you call the input model. For this example you don't have to use actual data; it's enough to use a random tensor of the appropriate shape. Also, note that there is a syntax error in `call`: `state_h` is not defined.

Comment: This is probably not related to your error, but you should prefer to use `tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell`. `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell` is deprecated in 2.0.

Comment: Thanks @DanMoldovan. I am able to fix the issue. 
Although, I am not using `tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell` because I want to use projection in lstm cell.

Comment: @DanMoldovan It will be really helpful if you can give your views on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369146/how-to-apply-layer-normalisation-in-lstmcell).